# "Unable to install the certificate" error when installing LetsEncrypt ssl certificate

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache2, lets-encrypt

I am trying to install Lets Encrypt, but with no success. I get the following error:

```
Keeping the existing certificate
Could not reverse map the HTTPS VirtualHost to the original

IMPORTANT NOTES:

Unable to install the certificate
Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at: /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.deals4u.co.il/fullchain.pem Your key file has been saved at: /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.deals4u.co.il/privkey.pem Your cert will expire on 2018-05-19. To obtain a new or tweaked version of this certificate in the future, simply run certbot again with the "certonly" option. To non-interactively renew all of your certificates, run "certbot renew"
```

My conf file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName deals4u.co.il
    ServerAlias www.deals4u.co.il
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did you set up the virtual host listening on 443?

Answer (score 0):

Removing `VirtualHost`s with similar `ServerName` fixed the problem for me.

If you don't have `VirtualHost`s in your config, try removing `ServerAlias`.